# Android Image Uploading on Localhost but not on online server

Tags: android, mysql, laravel, server

I am building a Laravel-based API. In the project, I want to upload image using post method to the API server
the image file is uploading on localhost database but when I try to upload the image on online server which is namecheap there image error code is 405.
I wasted 2 days but I don't now what is the error.
Please anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

**Here is android code**

```
  @Multipart
@POST("update-client")
Call<CustomerModel> update_user(@Part("id") RequestBody id,
                                @Part("name") RequestBody name, @Part("address") RequestBody address,
                                @Part("user_op_phone") RequestBody city,
                                @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                @Part("avatar") RequestBody image);


public void update_user_info(String name,String address,String no){
    progressDialog.show();

    RequestBody requestFile = null;
    MultipartBody.Part body = null;
    if(file!=null && file.length()>0) {
        requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("avatar", file.getName(), requestFile);
    }

    RequestBody  p_id =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),appSessionManager.getUserId());
    RequestBody  p_name =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),name);
    RequestBody  p_address = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),address);
    RequestBody  p_no = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),no);




    Call<CustomerModel> call1 = apiPHP.update_user(body,requestFile);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<CustomerModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CustomerModel> call, Response<CustomerModel> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            // VendorModel user1 = response.body();
            if(response.errorBody()==null){
                // if(response.code()==201) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CustomerModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

**Laravel Api routes is**

```
Route::post("update-client", "Client\ClientController@updateClient");
```

Comment: Http status code 405 means "Method Not Allowed" - indicates that your routes and the ajax call url doesn't match. Pls post your routes and the ajax call code

Comment: Data is posting without image to this route but i trying to upload the image with data the Error response code is 405.

Comment: Can't suggest any further without the code - would be like shooting in the dark

Comment: Route::post("update-client", "Client\ClientController@updateClient");

Comment: Does `apiPHP.update_user(body,requestFile)` make a post request to `update-client` can you verify in the android devtools